# Bash trap command behaves differently under two terminals

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, signal

I'm trying to write signal handlers in Bash scripts, testing under a Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Here I'm using the `trap` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "echo hi!" SIGINT SIGTERM

echo "pid is $$"
while true; do
    sleep 1;
done
```

After running `./test.sh`, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> gives me immediate `hi!` message under the current terminal. However, `kill <pid>` under another terminal has a 1 second delay printing `hi!`.

Can anybody tell why there the difference is? Is there a way that always trigger trap command immediately no matter what is going on? (like a sleep loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody tell why there the difference is?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> gets to `sleep` as well, while `kill <pid>` doesn't. In effect the latter way needs `sleep` to exit by itself before `hi!` is printed. What you call "1 second delay" is about 1 second at most and about 0.5 on average (it may take longer if the OS is very busy with other tasks).

You can clearly see the difference by using

```
pv -qL 1 <<< "0123456789"
```

instead of `sleep 1`.

Note that

```
kill -- -<pid>    # note the minus sign before PID
```

would send the signal to the entire process group, so to `sleep` (or `pv`) as well.

---

> Is there a way that always trigger trap command immediately no matter what is going on?

There is this question [*How to handle signals in bash during synchronous execution?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12856620/10765659)

From one of the answers:

> If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, **the trap will not be executed until the command completes**. When bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the `wait` builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the `wait` builtin to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.
>
> So, run your external program asynchronously and use `wait`. Kill it using `$!`.

In your case this method leads to the following quick and dirty script:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill "$!"; echo hi!' SIGINT SIGTERM

echo "pid is $$"
while true; do
    sleep 1 &
    wait
done
```

Comment: If we don't `kill "$!"` in trap, will we lost pid of the previous `sleep 1` after reception of a signal? In another word, will `wait` really return, or the OS just switches to execute signal handler then come back to wait later (looks like a return)?

Comment: @dastan "then come back to `wait` later" -- I think `wait` is no more. Why won't you test it? You can save the pid to a separate variable if you're afraid you can lose it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sleep 1` try `sleep 1 <&0 & wait` and then you'll find it quits right away.

The `sleep` command will remain running, however.

This works because bash's `wait` command can be interrupted by a signal, but the internal wait can't be.

Of course `<&0` isn't required for sleep, but for other commands that are being run in the background this way, stdin would be disconnected unless we deliberately connect it in this way.